# iOS Google Sign-in fetching user profile picture impossible?(NOT Google plus sign-in)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus-signin, google-signin

I'm trying to make google sign-in work in my app but have an issue.

(NOT a google plus sign-in, I'm using google sign-in)

I followed [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) and it works. I get userID, user.authentication.idToken, user.profile.name, and user.profile.email.

But I can't find out the way how I get the user profile picture.
Above google docs have no comment on that.

I searched web for hours but found about google plus sign-in only which I don't want.

I implemented Facebook sign-in in my app and they provide the url that fetches user profile picture.

Does google sign-in serve something like that?

This is my working code fetching user info but no picture.

Please help

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {

if (user) {
    NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
    NSString *token = user.authentication.idToken;   // Safe to send to the server
    NSString *name = user.profile.name;
    NSString *email = user.profile.email;
...
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you have to set  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES; and the use below code for get profile pic

```
    if ([GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.profile.hasImage)
    {
        NSUInteger dimension = round(thumbSize.width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        NSURL *imageURL = [user.profile imageURLWithDimension:dimension];
    }
```

## Swift Implementation:

```
let dimension = round(thumbSize.width * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);
let pic = user.profile.imageURLWithDimension(dimension)
```

Comment: Perfect answer .. :)

Comment: what is thumbsize in above answer?

Comment: @Sunita In my case i define thumbsize as constant like this   
#define thumbSize         CGSizeMake(130, 150)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
let dimension = round(imageSize.width * UIScreen.main.scale)
let pic = userInfo.profile.imageURL(withDimension: dimension)
```

imageSize.width is required width of image.

```
let dimension = round(100 * UIScreen.main.scale)
let pic = userInfo.profile.imageURL(withDimension: dimension)
```

Thanks Amit

Answer (score 0):

BOOL hashImage=user.profile.hasImage;

```
CGSize thumbSize=CGSizeMake(500, 500);
if (hashImage) {
    NSUInteger dimension = round(thumbSize.width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    NSURL *imageURL = [user.profile imageURLWithDimension:dimension];
    NSLog(@"image url=%@",imageURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

You need to sign in to your google account with this call:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

Then when the call gets the call back here:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        // Mange error
    } else {
       let dimension = round(MY_UIIMAGE_VIEW.bounds.width * UIScreen.main.scale)
       let pic = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: UInt(dimension))
       print("Image URL: \(pic)")
    }
}
```

This is the code it is working for me. It is an edit of @Techbee for Swift 5. I am using an image view to show the image, it is has a 75x75 frame, and the returned image from API is a 225x225 jpg.